# App Engine error after Python web app is deployed - BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I am running my web app on a standard environment on Python 3.7 and when I test it locally everything works fine. However, after I deploy my app I am receiving the following error when the app tries to save files to the `/tmp` location that I have designated:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This is how am designating the path to save as well as the file name.

```
file_num = os.urandom(10).hex()

handle, path = tempfile.mkstemp()

ytdl_format_options = {'format': 'bestaudio/best','outtmpl':path + 'song'+ file_num +'.mp3', 'quiet': True}
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error or if there is some type of config file setting that I am missing either on `app.yaml` or on gunicorn. I also tried locating the gunicorn files on the glcoud shell but they were not showing up in the directory.

I have noticed that my app will randomly work correctly when I commit new changes to files and re-deploy the app, however it will only work once and then if I immediately try running the function again it fails. This is the error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 279, in handle
    keepalive = self.handle_request(req, conn)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 348, in handle_request
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/six.py", line 625, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 331, in handle_request
    resp.write_file(respiter)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 403, in write_file
    if not self.sendfile(respiter):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 393, in sendfile
    sent += sendfile(sockno, fileno, offset + sent, count)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: Can you include some code showing how you're writing to `/tmp`?

Comment: How large is the data that you're trying to write to `/tmp` and what instance class are you using? (`/tmp` is a tmpfs partition using the instance's RAM). Are you cleaning up the `tmp` files after use?

Comment: I have edited my post to show how I am assigning a file destination path as well as the file name. I am currently not cleaning the /tmp folder after use however the program function will still randomly run fine. I've tried assigning to  different destination folders like /srv or /var but I still get the same error. The file sizes vary per client use, but the min - max size range should be between 3 mb and 10 mb. Right after I re-deploy the app it will randomly work once and if I immediately try to run it again it returns an error, but if I run the app locally it works fine every time.

Answer (score 1):

From [Filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#filesystem):

> The runtime includes a full filesystem. The filesystem is read-only
>   except for the location `/tmp`, which is a virtual disk storing data
>   in your App Engine instance's RAM.

So:

- using any location other than `/tmp` won't work
- the amount of available space is limited. Because of this your app needs to take care of deleting the temporary files after use. The behaviour you describe suggests the available space may only be enough for 1 of your files.

Another thing to consider is multiple parallel requests: if each of such request could create its own file, then the error could be hit because multiple files would be written simultaneously by different such requests. Adding a scheme limiting the number of requests processed in parallel would be a possible approach.

While not 100% certain I suspect the limit *may* also be dependent on the instance's total amount of RAM, in which case your app's configured [instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes) would matter as well. To check if this is true just temporarily configure an instance class with more RAM and see if that helps (without cleaning up the files maybe it'd work more than once before hitting the error, for example).

If the above suspicion is confirmed then choosing an appropriate instance class could also be an approach for addressing the problem.

Despite applying all the above it may still be possible to hit the issue, for example if some of the files you're writing are simply too big. If so then using the local filesystem is not appropriate for your app. A possible alternative would be to [store your files in Google Cloud Storage (GCS)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage) instead.

Comment: These are the changes I have made so far but none of them have fixed the issue:  
\
- changed instance_class to F4_1G on app.yaml 
\
- updated /etc/fstab settings to have a /tmp size of 4gb 
\
- unmounted the /tmp folder and remounted with 1gb of space 
\


I previously tried sending files directly to my GCS however these files are not just text, they can also be audio which resulted in even more problems.

Comment: How are you modifying fstab or (un)mount `/tmp` on GAE?

Comment: I went in to the root directory then ran: nano /etc/fstab. At first the system said the file was unconfigured so then I removed that line and input the following:   tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=1777,size=4GB 0 0. I then saved the changes to /etc/fstab. Is this method incorrect?

Comment: I just ran df -h /tmp and it says i have 9.8G available

Comment: Is the /tmp folder different after I run gcloud app deploy from when I just run the app locally with the command "python main.py"?

Comment: The /tmp on GAE has no relationship whatsoever with the one on your machine.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am not clear with my terminology this is my first time deploying a web app on GAE

Comment: I am referring to when I open the google cloud shell GAE and create a virtual environment on there to test run my app vs when I actually deploy the live app on GAE. When running the app before I deploy it and save to a path starting with ~/ it directs to /home after I deploy the app and save to a path starting with ~/ it directs to /srv . So i'm assuming the /tmp directory isn't the same before vs after the app is deployed, especially since when running the app before it's deployed it saves to /tmp with no problems regardless of iteration attempts

Comment: The Cloud Shell is also practically unrelated to your GAE instance, from GAE's perspective it's just like as your local machine. My answer applies only to the app deployed on GAE.

Comment: I just ran a new test on the app, where I forced the program to only save small text files to the /tmp folder when the app is deployed. The program now runs fine with no issues if I run it multiple times in a row. So this leads me to believe that the error I was previously experiencing might be due to the memory size of the /tmp folder that i'm trying to save to.

Comment: Is there a best practice for increasing the size of the /tmp folder I am sending files to when the app is deployed?

Comment: I think i'm getting closer to the main issue, I tried running the "return send file" function after passing it through a with open(filename,"rb") as file:
The error I am getting now is [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: Hi @Forbeez, can you confirm if the original issue from your question was solved? If this answer was helpful, please accept it to make it more visible for other people with similar issues.

Comment: @alextru my issue was never resolved. I was never able to get the requested files to save directly to the tmp folder consistently after my app was deployed on GAE.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean in your comment from Mar 6? Maybe add it as an update to your question and give a bit of code so we can help you better to solve this issue in its current state, and understand it from the beginning.